# No confirmation messages after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working in a `Rails 4.1.0` application in `cloud9 IDE`. I enter test info in the `fields: Name, Email, Comments` in the Contact Us form page, clicked submit and the following info displays in the address bar with no 'Message sent' confirmation:

https://manual-coder-rails/contacts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&contact%5Bname%5D=Nick&contact%5Bemail%5D=victorysupplys%40gmail.com&contact%5Bcomments%5D=Nice+web&commit=Submit

I entered no info in the fields (blank), clicked submit, the blank info is displayed in the address bar, again no 'Error' confirmation message:

https://manual-coder-rails/contacts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&contact%5Bname%5D=&contact%5Bemail%5D=&contact%5Bcomments%5D=&commit=Submit

I enter `bundle exec rails c` and `Contact.all` in the console, no entries are listed here and no entries are saved to the database:

> 2.3.0 :001 > Contact.all
>   Contact Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts"

```
> => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

I tried to figure out what the problem is in my code, having made several changes, but to no avail. Someone might notice something I do not. Here is my code for perusal and advice:

Contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end              

  def index
  end  

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      name = params[:contact][:name]
      email = params[:contact][:email]
      body = params[:contact][:comments]
      ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Message sent."
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Error occured, message has not been sent."
      redirect_to new_contact_path
    end
  end

  private
  def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts, only:[:new, :create], path_names: { new: ""}
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  root 'pages#home'
```

application.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
   <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
     <div class="alert alert-success", role="alert"<% key %>"Message sent!">   
       <% value %>
     </div>
     <div class="alert alert-danger", role="alert"<% key %>"Error occured, message not sent!"><% value %>
     </div>
     <button type="button", class="close", data-dismiss="alert", aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span>&times;></span></button>
     <%= value %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
 <%= yield %>
```

Comment: try <%= flash.inspect %> to see all of your flash. Also try setting flash.now[:success] to see if that helps.

Comment: @AndrewWei I applied the changes, still no confirmation messages and not saving to database..

Comment: If it's not saving it to the database its because there is errors on your model. print out the errors `puts @contact.errors.inspect`

Comment: @AndrewWei   The problem of saving to the database had been solved by making minor adjustments in the application.html.erb and contacts_controller.rb folders, but strange enough there is still no confirmation messages. I made several changes in code, still this problem eludes me. Quite stuck on this one!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're stating that the flash doesn't show on an error. `:danger` is not a default flash key. You'll need to either:

1. Update the view containing the flash to explicitly check for `:danger`, or
2. Change your controller to use `:alert` instead of `:danger`.